# Express 4 and socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

In the past, listening servers would be created in the app.js file so when you wanted to run your server you would use this command.

```
node app.js
```

I have recently gotten back into nodejs and am now having difficulty because in the past when I would listen to the server with my sockets like so -

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

where the server object was an http server, now running

```
node app.js
```

simply compiles the file, and in order to start a server I have to use the command

```
npm start
```

which apparently runs the script ./bin/www

browsing the web there are a couple of examples using express 4 and socket.io
BUT THEY ALL INITIALIZE A SERVER IN app.js!!!

I'm under the impression that if the default for the express application is to not have your server in app.js that doing so would be bad practice. Can anyone help guide me as to the best approach for using socket.io with express 4? Should I create an httpServer in app.js?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in creating a http server in `app.js` also [npm start](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-start.html) runs the `start` script defined in `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Where to Eat](https://github.com/johanan/Where-to-eat), particularly app.js.

The http server is defined in app.js:

```
var express = require('express'),
    socketio = require('./data/socket');
```

Next, pass the server to the init function (this is what socketio in app.js is used for) which is tells socket.io to listen on the passed server object:

```
//start up socket.io
socketio(server);
```

All of the socket event handlers are kept nice and bundled within /data/socket.

```
var socketio = require('socket.io'),

module.exports = initSockets;

function initSockets(server){
  var io = socketio.listen(server);
//…
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Point taken,  I've provided a brief explanation there.